# how to convert string(text) to number(integer) in vf page

Tags: visualforce, format

I am getting a field value in text format(eg :44.345). I want to use this value for division on vf page. how can i convert this to number format to be used for division

Comment: you can use parseInt("10") or parseFloat("10.33")

Comment: does it works on VF page?

Comment: use [`VALUE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) function. From documentation- `Converts a text string to a number`

Comment: @RohitMourya you asking parseInt("10") or parseFloat("10.33") is working in vf? yes it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For converting the text to number in Visualforce merge fields, you can use [VALUE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) function in merge fields

If you have property with name `division`, you can use following code for Visualforce:

```
{!VALUE(division) * 2}
```

For better control, do conversion in apex or JavaScript.